/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
I try to compile program consisted of two files. I connect them with header file. Here are these programs:
//memliib.hpp
#ifndef MEMLIB_H
#define MEMLIB_H

int daj_n();
char odkryj(int i);

#endif


//memlib.cpp
#include "memlib.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

static std::string oryginalne_karty;
static std::vector<bool> zgadniete;
static int zapytania = 0;
static int cukierki = 0;
static int poprz = -1;
static bool initialized = false;

static void initialize() {
    if (initialized)
        return;
    initialized = true;
    std::cin >> oryginalne_karty;
    zgadniete.resize(oryginalne_karty.size());
}

int daj_n() {
    initialize();
    return oryginalne_karty.size() / 2;
}

char odkryj(int i) {
    initialize();
    std::cout << "Pytasz o " << i << "-ta karte (" << oryginalne_karty[i - 1] << ")\n";
    if (i == poprz) {
        std::cout << "Spytano o juz odkryta karte.\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    zapytania++;
    if (zapytania % 2 == 1) {
        poprz = i;
    }
    else {
        if (oryginalne_karty[poprz - 1] == oryginalne_karty[i - 1]) {
            cukierki += !zgadniete[i - 1];
            zgadniete[poprz - 1] = zgadniete[i - 1] = true;
        }
        poprz = -1;
    }
    if (2 * cukierki == (int)oryginalne_karty.size()) {
        std::cout << "Hurra! Wydano wszystkie cukierki!!\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return oryginalne_karty[i - 1];
}


//mem.cpp
#include <string>
#include "memlib.hpp"

int main() {
    int n = daj_n();
    char c;
    c = odkryj(1);
    c = odkryj(5);
    c = odkryj(5);
    c = odkryj(1);
    c = odkryj(2);
    c = odkryj(4);
    c = odkryj(6);
    c = odkryj(3);
    return 0;
}

I compile it with following command:
$ g++ -O3 -static -std=c++20 memlib.cpp mem.cpp
And then get this error
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory

while program's linking.
I work on Fedora 40.
I've tried to install somehow missing libraries and I've looked for some .so files, but I 've not found.

Weird, I think all of those should've been installed by default with your compiler. Did you do anything unusual with your system?

I work on an external disk, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

The problem is resolved. I was missing static libraries on disk.

To install them was enough to type: yum install libstdc++-static.x86_64 and yum install glibc++-static
